# Phone Verification with the Twilio API using java

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

Implementing authentication in a project and using phone verification with the Twilio API but have run into an error that I later carried a simple test **with code I have added below**. Did a basic test with sample code I got from the official [twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api?code-sample=code-step-2-send-a-verification-token&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=7.x) from their site and had this error which I haven't been able to figure out.

> Here is the sample code.

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification;

public class Login {
    public final static String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public final static String AUTH_TOKEN = "auth_token";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        Verification verification = Verification.creator(
                "VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "+237677777777",
                "sms")
                .create();

        System.out.println(verification.getStatus());
    }
}
```

> Here is the error

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij
Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.exception.ApiException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 100] (through reference chain: com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification["send_code_attempts"])
    at com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification.fromJson(Verification.java:167)
    at com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.VerificationCreator.create(VerificationCreator.java:201)
    at com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.VerificationCreator.create(VerificationCreator.java:23)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
    at Login.main(Login.java:14)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 100] (through reference chain: com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification["send_code_attempts"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1442)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1216)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromEmpty(StdDeserializer.java:639)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:360)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:530)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:528)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:417)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3242)
    at com.twilio.rest.verify.v2.service.Verification.fromJson(Verification.java:165)
    ... 4 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please any help will be much appreciated, im new to Twilio.

Comment: why you did not use  .setTo() method?

Comment: Yes, @VK321 That is true but if you look well you will realize that it is for the VerificationCheck Method. I get the SMS notification quite alright but immediately runs to that error and if I check the console I get the status of verification set to pending.

Comment: OK, its hard to test as API is paid.... if i was at you, I would try to get earlier/stable version of twillio jar or dependencies to test.

Comment: This looks like there is an issue deserializing the JSON response from the API. Are you using the latest version of the Twilio Java library (which is 7.47.4 right now)?

Comment: @philnash      Yes, I'm using that version.

Comment: This has been raised as a [bug on the project GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/issues/517) so I recommend following that. You may be able to roll the Java library back to 7.47.3, which doesn't try to do that parsing, and carry on working for now.

Comment: This should now be fixed in version 7.47.6 which was just released. Give that a go and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Great!!! @philnash Works just fine with the new 7.48.0

Comment: Glad to hear it, thanks @LeoSammy!

Answer (score 0):

Halo found a walk around this bug. In the meanwhile, while Twilio handles that you can use this way to get the verification code if you are facing same issue :)
I used the java **Process class** and the **curl to post**

Here is the code.

```
void method(String var) throws IOException {

  String command ="curl -X POST https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/" + SERVICE_ID + "/Verifications --data-urlencode To=" + phoneNumber +
                        " --data-urlencode Channel=sms -u " + ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + AUTH_TOKEN;

  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  process.getInputStream();
// some code
}
```